# wit.ai message api call from java

Tags: nlp, chatbot, facebook-chat, wit.ai, facebook-chatbot

I am making call to wit.ai message API from java. It works and i can get the intent and entities for the message as per my story definition.
However I have doubt - when i will be adding multiple stories to my bot on wit.ai platform, i need to 
use the same wit.ai URL. In that case how exactly i will extract the intents and entities from the wit response? 
Message from user could be for any story message. For extracting entity value from the 
wit.ai response i need to specify entity name (in json response) in my method. Lets say - entities.[0].value

Any idea how can i do that in java? Also am not getting how exactly the custom actions defined in the story has to be implemented and use in java.

I tried sample POC in node.js(by following the messenger.js file) and it works fine for custom actions defined. But am not 
getting how to do it in java?

Any help/pointers in this regard greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even iam looking for the same. Though in the HTTP API they have given how to call conversation involving actions there is no description how to create actions with Java. It is descriptive in case of node js but not java. Let me know if you make any breakthrough. I have written to the support team yet to hear back

Comment: Aakash - I used converse API call from java and it worked. As far as creating actions defined in your story, you to need to provide manual mapping for action name received from converse API call response and in your java code call that appropriate function. However I see that lot many java code need to be written to handle/manage context/actions etc. But it works. You can try it.